# Asterisks Shapes

Tags: c++, shapes

I need to make this this shape out (or similar) of asterisks:

```
 *           *   
 * *       * * 
 * * * * * * *
 * *       * * 
 *           *
```

I somewhat know how to do 'nested for loops'. I can only do one triangle though and I need two one side by side...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"Insert A Number...\n" <<endl;
    int i;
    int j;
    int size;
    cin >> size;
    for(i=1;i<size*2;i+=2)
    {
        cout<<endl;
        for(j=(size-i)/2+1;j>=0;j--)
        {
            cout<<' ';
        }
        for(j=0;i>j;j++)
        {
            cout<<'$';
        }
    }
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it needs nested loops to make this shape?

Comment: What is the size of the triangle you've displayed above? In other words, what should the user enter to get that output?

Comment: Well, don't believe everything your teacher says :-P. Though he might expect you're solving this with nested loops. Just try harder ...

Comment: Could it be you are printing '$' instead of '*'?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I'm not that dumb haha.

Comment: Reread your code.  The code you posted doesn't print any '*'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Insert A Number...\n" << endl;
    int size;
    cin >> size;

    int user_rows = size;
    int user_cols = ceil(user_rows / 2.0)*2;

    for (int row = 1; row <= user_rows; row++) { //print each row of asterisks

        int asterisksPerSide = (row * 2 <= user_rows) ? row : user_rows - row + 1;
        int spacesTotal = user_cols - (2 * asterisksPerSide);

        for (int asterisksPrinted = 0; asterisksPrinted < asterisksPerSide; asterisksPrinted++) { //print first part of row
            cout << "*";
        }

        for (int spacesPrinted = 0; spacesPrinted < spacesTotal; spacesPrinted++) { //print spaces
            cout << " ";
        }

        for (int asterisksPrinted = 0; asterisksPrinted < asterisksPerSide; asterisksPrinted++) { //print last part of row
            cout << "*";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some observations to help you:

1. The first N lines contain the number of asterisks as the line
   number.
2. Consider the shape to be a rectangle, where one triangle is
   asterisks, the other spaces.
3. The second shape on the same line is a mirror of the first.
4. The lines after N decrement the number of asterisk, but increase the
   number of spaces.

For example, given N as 10:
Line 1 has 1 asterisk,  10 - 1 spaces, 10 - 1 spaces, 1 asterisk.
Line 2 has 2 asterisks, 10 - 2 spaces, 10 - 2 spaces, 2 asterisks.
Line 3 has 3 asterisks, 10 - 3 spaces, 10 - 3 spaces, 3 asterisks.
Line 4 has 4 asterisks, 10 - 4 spaces, 10 - 4 spaces, 4 asterisks.
//...
Line 11 has 9 asterisks, 10 - 9 spaces, 10 - 9 spaces, 9 asterisks.
Line 12 has 8 asterisks, 10 - 8 spaces, 10 - 8 spaces, 8 asterisks.
Line 13 has 7 asterisks, 10 - 7 spaces, 10 - 7 spaces, 7 asterisks.

See any patterns?

Answer (score 0):

Your code prints a triangle with the peak at the top. What you want is a sideways triangle -- two of them, in fact. To figure out how to do this, work through an example on paper.

In the case you displayed above, assuming the input was `3`, how would you print each line?

- Line 1 has one star at left and one star at right.
- Line 2 has two stars at left and two stars at right.
- Line 3 has three stars at left, one star in the middle, and three stars at right.
- Line 4 has two stars at left and two stars at right.
- Line 5 has one star at left and one star at right.

An easy way to get the number of stars on each side is to count up from `1` to `3`, then count back down from `2` to `1`. Now you just have to calculate the number of spaces per line. There's also the matter of the lone star in the center of the longest line, which means that you'll have to deal with that line separately.

The program below prints out exactly the output you've displayed in your question when the user enters `3`. Notice how I defined a pair of helper functions, `repeat()` and `printRow()`, to avoid writing the same code multiple times.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void repeat(int n, string s) {
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    cout << s;
  }
}

void printRow(int size, int i) {
  repeat(i, "* ");
  repeat(2*(size-i)+1, "  ");
  repeat(i-1, "* ");
  cout << "*" << endl;
}

int main() {
    cout << "Enter a number:" << endl;
    int size;
    cin >> size;
    for (int i = 1; i < size; ++i) {     // Rows of increasing length.
      printRow(size, i);
    }
    repeat(2*size, "* ");                // Middle row.
    cout << "*" << endl;
    for (int i = size-1; i >= 1; --i) {  // Rows of decreasing length.
      printRow(size, i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If I present you a homework assignment will you provide the program for me?  Most of the time we try to get these posters to think, rather than spoon-feeding them answers.

Comment: This isn't a assignment. It's practice!

Comment: How come you accepted another solution when it doesn't print the result shown in your question? Mine does.

Answer (score 0):

Think of how you can do it *line-by-line* instead of thinking left-to-right if you're going to use for loops.